# How to write multiple dictionaries to a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM6UU.png)When I run the above code only the Games_shop dictionary is getting written to the something.txt not the Fruit_shop. Can u please help me know what change should i make in the code to get the Fruit_shop dictionary written to the file along with a small justification. Thanks in Advance!!

```
def writing_to_file(shop) -> None:
    file_name = "something" + '.txt'
    with open('C:/Users/xyz/PycharmProjects/Shops/{0}'.format(file_name), 'w') as f:
        for key, value in shop.items():
            f.write(key + '\n')
            for key1, value1 in value.items():
                f.write(f"{key1} : {value1}\n")
            f.write(f"{'}'}")


Fruit_shop = {
    'Fruits {':{
        'A':'Apple',
        'B':'Ball'
    }
}
Games_shop = {
    'Games {':{
        'C':'Cricket',
        'F':'Football'
    }
}

writing_to_file(Fruit_shop)
writing_to_file(Games_shop)
```

Comment: Post your code, formatted, in the question please.

Comment: My code  is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM6UU.png

Comment: @CaptainCaveman I was unable to attach my code to some syntax issue so i have pasted my code here https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM6UU.png , please help

Comment: The rules of SO state that you should not post an image of your code. How can someone reproduce code that is in an image? Do you expect them to retype your code? If you surround your code with three back ticks it will be formatted. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: @abhishekravoor you can use copy paste to put the code into the question: https://seniortechgroup.com/programs/the-basics/cut-copy-and-paste-tutorial/

Comment: @Caridorc Thanks for the link but still its throwing the error of code not formated properly

Comment: @abhishekravoor do not worry, we are here to help you. You can select the code and press the `{}` button in the editor to make it look better. another chance is using triple backquote `\`\`\`` at the start and end of the code

Comment: @Caridorc Thanks a lot Mate!! The code is up

Comment: @CaptainCaveman Thanks a lot buddy, I think now the code is up!

Comment: `'w'` mode erases any existing file contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem derives from a misunderstanding of the `mode` argument of the `open` function. I suggest the [Reading and Writing Files section of the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) and more specifically, the [documentation of the `open` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

In short, the `"w"` (write) option deletes everything, so you need to use the `"a"` (append) option instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy for clearing the doubt I had! Will go through the documentation!

Answer (score 0):

Every time you open a file with the `open` function and the write flag 'w' there are two options: A new file will be created if it doesn't exist, or the existing file will be truncated and its previous contents will be cleaned up for the new writing. It's not something python-specific, it's an operating system's standard.

Your `Fruit_shop` dict was actually written to the file, but the second time you call the function `writing_to_file` it truncates the file and overwrites it with only the `Games_shop` dict.

If you want to append contents to your file use the append flag 'a' instead of 'w'. To further information, look at the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) for the fopen system call for a list of all possible flags and their effects.